# Proving a particular "basic" property of the Hilbert symbol.

Tags: solution-verification, p-adic-number-theory

I wish to prove the following lemma.

**Lemma.** Let $(a,b)_p$ be the Hilbert symbol evaluated at the prime $p$. Then, it satisfies the following property $$(a,b)_p=(ac^2,b)_p=(a,bc^2)_p.$$
I guess I see the rough idea: given the equation $ax^2+by^2=z^2$, we wish to see that the solutions to the equation $ac^2x^2+by^2=z^2$. Assume $(x,y,z)\neq (0,0,0)$ as the result is clear if not. Then, it follows that $(cx, y, z)$ is a solution to this equation which is non-zero and hence, is equal to $(a,b)_p$.

Do you think this is formal enough to prove the lemma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write: For $\color{red}{c\neq 0}$ we have that:

$(x,y,z) \neq(0,0,0)$ is a solution to $ac^2X^2+bY^2=Z^2$

if and only if

$(cx,y,z) \neq(0,0,0)$ is a solution to $aX^2+bY^2=Z^2$.

Comment: Ah I see, that little addition does make it a lot better. Thank you, for all your help in my $p$-adic learning...much appreciated!